# While applying linear regression on wine.csv dataset, python reads all columns available as a single column

Tags: python-2.7

While applying linear regression on wine.csv dataset, python reads all columns available as a single column. Please can you fix this error.

Here is my code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('wine1.csv')
df.info()
OUTPUT:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4898 entries, 0 to 4897
Data columns (total 1 columns):
fixed acidity;"volatile acidity";"citric acid";"residual sugar";"chlorides";"free sulfur dioxide";"total sulfur dioxide";"density";"pH";"sulphates";"alcohol";"quality"    4898 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 38.3+ KB

df.head()
```

OUTPUT:

```
    fixed acidity;"volatile acidity";"citric acid";"residual sugar";"chlorides";"free sulfur dioxide";"total sulfur dioxide";"density";"pH";"sulphates";"alcohol";"quality"
0   7;0.27;0.36;20.7;0.045;45;170;1.001;3;0.45;8.8;6
1   6.3;0.3;0.34;1.6;0.049;14;132;0.994;3.3;0.49;9...
2   8.1;0.28;0.4;6.9;0.05;30;97;0.9951;3.26;0.44;1...
3   7.2;0.23;0.32;8.5;0.058;47;186;0.9956;3.19;0.4...
4   7.2;0.23;0.32;8.5;0.058;47;186;0.9956;3.19;0.4...
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' default CSV reader reads a comma separated file, but your data is separated with semicolons.  You need to change your delimiter from comma to semicolon.  See this doc for more detail: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html